# Framed environment covers caption of figure in afterpage

Tags: framed, afterpage

I'm using packages `framed` to create my own quote environment with a nice frame. However, when using the package `afterpage` to shift a figure to the next page and the first thing on the next page is a frame, than the frame covers the caption of the figure. This does not happen if there's some text between the figure and the frame.

[image: caption covered, if no text between picture and frame]

How can I change my framed environment so that it does not cover the caption?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{F0F0F0}
\definecolor{darkerlightgray}{HTML}{E0E0E0}

\newenvironment{myQuote}{%
    \OuterFrameSep=0pt % space before and after box
  \def\FrameCommand{%
        \fboxsep=6pt %padding thickness
    \fcolorbox{darkerlightgray}{lightgray}%
  }%
  \MakeFramed{\hsize\linewidth\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}%
  \noindent% disable indenting first paragraph
  \begin{adjustwidth}{}{7pt}%
  \vspace{-0.5\parskip}%
}
{%
  \vspace{2pt}\end{adjustwidth}\endMakeFramed\vspace{-\parskip}%
}

\renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{myQuote}\em}{\end{myQuote}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}

\lipsum[2]

\afterpage{
    \begin{figure}[htp]
        \rule{\textwidth}{0.2\textheight}
            \caption{my first figure}
    \end{figure}
}

\lipsum[6]

\begin{quote}
    Quote OK
\end{quote}

\lipsum[6]

\begin{quote}
    Quote not OK (caption is covered)
\end{quote}

\lipsum[1]

\afterpage{
    \begin{figure}[htp]
            \rule{\textwidth}{0.2\textheight}
            \caption{my second figure}
    \end{figure}
}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{quote}
    Quote OK
\end{quote}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recognized, that `tcolorbox` handles footnotes differently than the `framed` package. Since I need all footnotes to be on the bottom of the page, I fiddled with the package code and came up with this solution:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\tracingpatches
\patchcmd{\MakeFramed}{\penalty\@M \vskip 2\baselineskip \vskip\height}{\penalty\@M \vskip 1pt \vskip\height}{}{}
\patchcmd{\MakeFramed}{\penalty9999 \vskip -2\baselineskip \vskip-\height}{\penalty9999 \vskip -1pt \vskip-\height}{}{}
\makeatother
```

I don't guarantee that this will work for all cases, however, the problem in the MWE and also other I had in my PhD thesis went away. Maybe someone can comment on whether this is a good solution or how to make it even better.